# Inject resource into Jersey ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, wildfly

I look for way to inject resource in jax-rs (Jersey) filter (`ContainerRequestFilter`)

This is my filter

```
@Provider
@Secure
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final String HEADER_PERFIX = "UUID ";

    @Resource(name = "DataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException { 
        String header = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if(header == null || !header.startsWith(HEADER_PERFIX)) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }

        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {

            String query = 
                    "update sessions set expire = now() + interval '1 hour' " + 
                    "where token = ?::uuid";// and expire > now()";

            try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
                String token = header.substring(HEADER_PERFIX.length());
                statement.setString(1, token);

                if(statement.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                    requestContext.setProperty("uuid", token);
                }
                else {
                    requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and `web.xml`

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>DataSource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

        <mapped-name>java:jboss/datasources/erp</mapped-name>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

in this case `dataSource` is not null, but with the wrong value (into H2 database). I use wildfly 10.1

**Update** 
For now, I use the constructor for manually lookup of resource

```
@Provider
@Secure
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final String HEADER_PERFIX = "UUID ";

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public AuthenticationFilter() {
        try {
            dataSource = (DataSource)InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/DataSource");
        }
        catch(NamingException e) {
            dataSource = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException { 
        String header = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if(header == null || !header.startsWith(HEADER_PERFIX)) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }

        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {

            String query = 
                    "update sessions set expire = now() + interval '1 hour' " + 
                    "where token = ?::uuid";// and expire > now()";

            try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
                String token = header.substring(HEADER_PERFIX.length());
                statement.setString(1, token);

                if(statement.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                    requestContext.setProperty("uuid", token);
                }
                else {
                    requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
@Singleton
public class DataSourceProvider {
    @Resource(name = "DataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public DataSource getDefualtDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

and filter

```
@Provider
@Secure
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final String HEADER_PERFIX = "UUID ";

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException { 
...
```

p.s. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

1) Use a CDI producer field to make your datasource `@Resource` available as a CDI bean.

2) Add a CDI scope annotation (`@ApplicationScoped`, `@Dependent`) to your `ContainerRequestFilter` to turn it into a CDI bean.

Then you should be able to `@Inject` the data source.

By the way, on a Java EE server, there is no need to work with JDBC connections and prepared statements. Consider using an `EntityManager` instead.

Comment: It does not work that way. DataSourtse again points to the h2 database (I use postgresql).
For JDBC, the project does not use ORM framework so watch him do only with jdbc.